# How to rename the "Repro Steps" field to "Description" in VSTS Bug work item

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to rename the "Repro Steps" field to "Description" in VSTS Bug work item, Is there any way to do this via Rest API?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, renaming a field or changing the field type aren’t supported actions in VSTS, you can check [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/process/customize-process-field#rename-field) article. Also if you change it in web portal, you just can rename the label, so if you retrieve work items through query, you still need to use Repro Steps field instead of the renamed label.

Secondly, you can update workitem type definition by using [updateWorkItemTypeDefinition(),](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1#method_updateWorkItemTypeDefinition) however, it is limited in VSTS, you can’t do it in VSTS.